# jupyter notebook: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:

Tags: python, operating-system, dataset, conv-neural-network

I got images in this file[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mEvI.jpg)

and i want to load it into my code to use it for train a CNN model, and I'm using this code:
**note : i used plt.imshow() and break method just to desply the first image**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

DATADIR = "X:/wavess/PYDATA"
CATEGORIES = ["healthy","parkinson"]

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
    z = os.listdir(path)
    for img in z :
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img))
        plt.imshow(img_array)
        plt.show
        break
    break
```

when i run this code i keep getting this error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'X:/wavess/PYDATA\healthy'

**can any one tell me why I'm getting this error? and how i can solve this problem**

​

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I had to put "r" before the string, so it'll be like this:

```
 DATADIR = r'X:/wavess/PYDATA'
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
DATADIR = "X:\wavess\PYDATA"
```

Comment: I tried it but still getting the same error